# java servlet PrintWriter alternative

Tags: java, servlets, printwriter

I am new to Java and servlets. I was trying to develop a small web project in which I have one java servlet. As per the J2EE materials, to print something from servlet we should object (out) of PrintWriter. And also I should write html code inside out.println(). If my page is quite big then this method of printing seems to be not comfortable. Do we have any other easiest way to print large pages of data from servlet

Regards,
Manohar

Answer (score 1):

No, you're looking at information that's outdated.  (FYI - prefer "Java EE" to "J2EE".  That acronym was true in 1999 when J2EE was announced, but it's old fashioned now.  We're well beyond version 2.)

I would say writing HTML in a servlet is a very bad idea.

A better solution is to use templating to marry data into a template and generate HTML that way.

If you want to stick with the Java EE stack, you should use JSP and JSTL.  A JSP is an HTML servlet generator template.  It gets compiled to a servlet that writes HTML for you.  If you stick with JSTL it'll be "taggy" and look more like HTML.

I prefer Velocity templates to JSP these days.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the servlet for your database access layer and business logic and then forward the request to a JSP for the view

see here: http://www.datadisk.co.uk/html_docs/jsp/jsp_mvc_tutorial.htm